# usar o <p:contextMenu> com o <p:editor>

Tags: primefaces

Tentei usar o *contextMenu* do *Primefaces* com o componente Editor, mas não funciona. O menu só aparece se clicar com o botão direito sobre as barras de ferramentas. O corpo do componente Editor recebe o nome do id concatenado com `_input` tentei usar isso no atributo `for` do componente *contextMenu* mas aí a página nem abre pois não é possível localizar o id o que é lógico pois somente existirá após o processo de *parser* do jsf.

```
<p:editor id="e" 
          height="430"
          widgetVar="editorHtml"
          value="#{m.texto}" />
<p:contextMenu for="e">
    <p:menuitem value="Teste" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Alguém saberia de fazer o *contextMenu* funcionar com o editor?

Comment: Eu criei uma página e tentei resolver. Não consegui. Está relacionado com o `<iframe>` criado pelo `<p:editor>`. Acho que seu problema pode ser resolvido com JavaScript.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rodrigo por seu tempo e pela ajuda! A resposta que obtive de um dos desenvolvedores do Primefaces: "Não é possível". Mas como você disse acho que dá pra resolver com JS, porém no caso eu vou mudar de estratégia e tentar uma abordagem diferente. Mais uma vez obrigado.